# sql server 2012 upgrade cannot select default instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade SQl Server 2008 Express with Advanced Tools to SQL Server 2012 Standard.

The problem is, the upgrade wizard, will not let me select the DEFAULT INSTANCE "MSSQLSERVER".

There are two Instances currently;
"SQLEXPRESS" (which was installed by an application)
and
"MSSQLSERVER", the default which was installed by me - Express with Advanced tools.

The problem is - I can only select "SQLEXPRESS" or shared components
It will not let me select the "MSSQLSERVER" Instance ID - even though it is listed in the Installed Instances grid.

On the select instance screen "default instance" radio button is grayed out.

Am I being stupid and blind ?
Why can I not select the default instance ?

"SQLEXPRESS" is version 10.2.4000.0

"MSSQLSERVER" is version 10.50.1600.1 as is the shared components

Any ideas on where my ignorance lies greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [apply Service Pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527041) 1 (at least, SP2 is available too) to bring the version up to [10.50.2500](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/faqs-1/sql-server-versions/2008-r2) (at least, .2500 is SP1).

Your current 10.50.1600 is RTM and an [upgrade from this is not supported.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)

FYI, the SQLEXPRESS instance is at SP2 already: 10.50.4000 (or 10.0.4000 if not R2)

Comment: actually - SQLEXPRESS is 10.2.4000 not 10.50.4000 if that makes a difference

Comment: which is weird - I don't even see that in the versions list... hmmmm.

Comment: A known issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/624341/version-numbering-is-not-consistent